# database design: X:X to 1:many vs X:X to 0:many

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, schema, mysql-workbench

(edited 1/5 10:22hr. added some explanation about my notation. And added some additional information I received)

I am doing a course on database design and currently we're doing ERD's and designing db's in MySQL worksbench. Think 1st, 2nd and 3rd NF, creating schema, tables, constraints, etc.
Most of it is pretty clear to me.

**However there's one aspect where things remain unclear**: the **X:X to 1:many** relationship vs the **X:X to 0:many** relationship (meaning: whatever to 0:many, vs whatever to 1:many,  etc).
In some cases it's obvious, in others not so much. Whenever it's unclear to me, it's mostly something like this:

**Example :**
an artist has 1 to many paintings. A painting has 1-and only 1 artist.

Relationship:

|artist| 1:1 -------- 1:many |painting|

the same in another notation
|artist| ||------------ 1< |painting|

This seems fair, but....Then there's the thought: I could be a new artist, not having produced a painting yet.
Or: I could be entering a new artist into a artist table, not yet having entered his paintings yet (which could lead to a practical issue).

**Another example:**
A workshop has 1 to many participants. A participant enters 0-to-many workshops.

Relationship:

|workshop| many:0 ------- 1:many |participant|

Okay. However: a workshop could have 0 participants (no one want to participate, probably leading to cancellation).
Or: I could be entering a new workshop into a table, not having added any participants yet.

**Another example:**
An event is held at 1 only 1 location. A location had 1 to many events.

Relationship: |event| many:1 -------- 1:1 |location|

However, maybe you're entering a new (future) location, and there have not been events there yet.

Long shorty short: I am having a hard time establishing the minimal cardinality in cases like above.

Also, when I'm designing a db and get Workbench to forward engineer the SQL for creating the tables (based on my ERD), there **doesn't seem to be any difference between a X to 1/many vs a X to 0/many variant**. Which makes me wonder: what's the actual (practical) effect or implication of doing one or the other? Maybe the implications (further down the road) make for an easier choice?

Can anyone explain this matter in a simple (fool-proof) way?

Looking forward to understanding!

Addition 1/5:

I've talked about my question/issue with a teacher. He agreed with me that  certain minimum cardinalities could lead to a deadlock:
one table cannot be inserted without there being a occurence in the other, and vice versa.
He explained to me that the ERD diagram is a logical model, not perse a fysical model. In other words, the ERD's minimum cardinality is not neccessarily for technical implementation.

Well, if that is the case, I understand his point. Usually an artist has at least one painting. A workshop normally has at least one participant. A location usually has at least one event. So on a logical level, that seems fine.

On a technical/implementation level, it is another deal. You should be able to enter a artist, workshop or location without there already being occurrences in  another table.

My question now is:

1. is this true? Is a ERD a logical model, not a technical model?
2. and if that is so, WHAT is the reason for adding the minimum cardinality? It seems of little use.

Comment: many in a relationship can be 0. In mysql you cannot force through FKs (which represent relationships) that a parent immediately has at least 1 child - this can only be done through application logic. From a practical RDBMs point of view, requiring a parent to have a child immediately is a chicken-and-egg problem (you need to create the parent record first, so you know its PK that you set in the child record). This is usually taken care of application logic and transactions.

Comment: An artist doesn't necessarily have any paintings.  The paintings may not be recorded in the database, or they may never have painted anything in their life, only photos or dance routines.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of to enforce a minimum of 1 relationship is to have a `primary` relationship.  Take a database with `person`, `address` and a table linking the two `person_address`.  Neither the `person` or the `address` refers to the other, only the link table does that.  Thus you have a 0-many : 0-many relationship.  But, if you add a `primary_address_id` column to the `person` table, you can enforce that a person can't be created until it's primary address is created first And that the person is created With that address, thus enforcing the minimum of one.  This is unusual.

Comment: see: https://www.damirsystems.com/sql-x-to-y/

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is no way to enforce a minimum of 1 occurence in a FK relationship?

Comment: "X to one/many" is not standard notation or terminology. Do you mean X:1..many ie X to 1-to-many? There are multiple ER & pseudo-ER methods, with different uses of the term "relationship" (association vs FK), notions of cardinalities, ways of describing & diagramming, etc. So you need to tell us yours. What is your textbook/reference name & edition? Where & why are you 1st stuck or uncertain in following it? Quote relevant definitions, notations & heuristics. (The "Entity-relationship model" Wikipedia article gives some idea of the variety in methods.) PS Don't add "EDIT"s, just edit.

Comment: My comment may have motivated you to edit, but you haven't edited per my comments & you've edited contrary to my comments. PS "Logical model" & "physical model" both have multiple common meanings & "technical model" does not have common meanings. Again: Textbook name, edition & section(s), etc etc. PS https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3404097+cardinality+relationship

Comment: @philip: In my course I am learing it like  >|-------0<  and ||-----------0|. Elsewhere it is noted in a different style. It is really not important to me in this stage. I just want people to understand what I am saying. Hence my edit. And I think you (and other) do understand my story now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's continue with your artist::paintings relationship, I think that's the clearest.  When we say 1 to many, we often mean 0/1 to 0/many, but not all the 4 permutations work or are meaningful.

1. How does "I can have no artists with no paintings" sound?  That's the zero-to-zero permutation.  It does not sound wrong, but it's a degenerate case that is of no use to us.
2. 1 artist to 0 paintings is OK, as matbailie described, and presents no problems.
3. 1 artist to many paintings is OK, and is the main use case.
4. 0 artists to many paintings is just not correct and should not be supported in the model.  A painting must have an artist.

Because cases 1 & 4 don't work, it is not really correct to say 0/1 to 0/many.  It is more correct to characterize the cardinality as 1 to 0/many, which encompasses cases 2 & 3 above.

You might say, 'but there are cases where we don't know the artist so we should leave an opportunity to have paintings with no artists'.  This statement feels to me like you are leaving the realm of the ERD and entering into physical design.  From a design standpoint you could just as easily say there **is** an artist we just don't know who, so let's create an UNKNOWN ARTIST record and connect those paintings  to it.

Your second example (workshops::participants) looks more like a 0/many to 0/many.  If you run through the same 4 permutations,  they all look credible, though the 0-to-0 case still seems kind of ludicrous.

Your last example is another 1 to 0/many because events without locations cannot be held.  When you get to the physical level you can talk about the best way to handle virtual events.

So, none of your examples seem to show a true zero-to-many (which is more accurately stated 0/1 to 0/many).  I'm thinking they are pretty rare, if they exist at all.  It would have to be associated with some kind of optional activity where if you did enroll in it there were a constrained set of choices.

Comment: That is a nice and clear explanation. I follow your reasoning.

Comment: That is a nice and clear explanation. I follow your reasoning and have the feeling that you in fact say dat often the 1 to 0/many is the case. The reason I brought it up here, is because in my course many excercise solutions are diplaying a 1 to 1/many relationship, where I feel a 1 to 0/many is more realistic.  The only thing left to wonder is: what does MySQL Workbench 'do' when you design a to-1/many vs to-0/many. I cannot help but wonder that it changes NOTHING (under the hood).....

Comment: Once you get to a physical implementation I don't believe there is any way to instantiate a true 1-to-1/many constrained relationship.  Think about it, you've already got a constraint that won't allow a painting without an artist and now you want to forbid artists without paintings - no matter which record I choose to add first, I am violating a constraint briefly.  Maybe if you had a data base that allowed deferral of constraint checks until commit, but you would have to add everything under program control, and deletes would be fubar for the same reason. My advice: code it into the app!

Answer (score 0):

But... A participant can be in 0-N workshops. So that needs to be many-to-many.

In general "zero" is a degenerate case of "1" or "N"; it is rarely worth worrying about.

I like to start by identifying the "entities" in the model.  Your participant, workshop, painting, event, artist, location are excellent examples of such.  Then I look for "relations" between obvious pairs.

I say there are only 3 cases.  And I like to remember that the two "entities" are manifested as two "database tables":

- 1:1 -- At which point I ask why the two entities (database tables) are not merged together.  The two tables share the same unique key.
- 1:many -- Represented by the id of the "1" as a column in the "many" table.
- Many:many -- This needs a link table between the two tables.  This linking table has two ids.

"Id" means a unique key for a table.  It is usually a number, but that is not a requirement.

For "0"...

- 1:0 or many:0 -- You may need a `LEFT JOIN` to provide `NULLs` when the entry on the "0" side is missing
- Many:many -- If either id is non-existent (the zero case), then there are no rows for that relationship.

Then comes defining the `INDEXes` for efficient access.  And, optionally, `FOREIGN KEYs` for integrity.  The indexes that represent how two entities are related are prime candidates for FKs.  Other `INDEXes` should be added to optimize `WHERE` clauses in SQL queries.

In all cases, the id/FK/index may be "composite" -- meaning that it is two or more columns that are used for a single id/FK/index.

Comment: Thank you for you contribution. It's not that I don't understand the relationships or the technical implementation thereof, it's the fact that the 'solution' of my exercises often show a  (for example) 1/1 to 1/many relationship, where I am thinking: this could/should be 1/1 to 0/many relationship. So it's about the minimum cardinality of 0 vs 1.  From the answers here I gather that I am making to much of this. It's more often than not a 0, but in reality it doesn't even matter. I understand that is more likely to be solved by application logic, than technical database implementation.